# convert string to date in java in format 2012-07-27

Tags: java

i have the input string as 2012-07-27 and i want the output as date but with the same format like 2012-07-27

my code is

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

```
    try {
        Date today = df.parse("20-12-2005");
        System.out.println("Today = " + df.format(today));

                 } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

my output is

```
Fri Jul 27 00:00:00 IST 2012
```

but i want to return the date object like like 2012-07-26 23:59:59 instead of a string  any help please

any help is very thank full

Comment: Dates don't have format.

Comment: Use `format` method instead of `parse'

Comment: It sounds like you already *have* the string you want. You're trying to go from "2012-07-27" to "2012-07-27" - what am I missing here?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 7):

You can use your same `SimpleDateFormat` you used to parse the date, to format the date into a string.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date1 = formatter.parse("2012-07-27");
System.out.println(date1); // prints Fri Jul 27 00:00:00 IST 2012
System.out.println(formatter.format(date1)); // prints 2012-07-26
```

Comment: thanks ,,  but i want to return the date object instead of a string like 2012-07-26 23:59:59 any help please

Answer (score 1):

First, I think it's important to note that `System.out.println` implicitly invokes the `toString` method of its argument. The argument must be an `Object` or a subclass of it. And `Date` is a subclass of `Object`. That being said, take a look at the 1.7 `Date#toString` implementation,

```
public String toString() {
        // "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
        BaseCalendar.Date date = normalize();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(28);
        int index = date.getDayOfWeek();
        if (index == gcal.SUNDAY) {
            index = 8;
        }
        convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[index]).append(' ');                        // EEE
        convertToAbbr(sb, wtb[date.getMonth() - 1 + 2 + 7]).append(' ');  // MMM
        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getDayOfMonth(), 2).append(' '); // dd

        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getHours(), 2).append(':');   // HH
        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getMinutes(), 2).append(':'); // mm
        CalendarUtils.sprintf0d(sb, date.getSeconds(), 2).append(' '); // ss
        TimeZone zi = date.getZone();
        if (zi != null) {
            sb.append(zi.getDisplayName(date.isDaylightTime(), zi.SHORT, Locale.US)); // zzz
        } else {
            sb.append("GMT");
        }
        sb.append(' ').append(date.getYear());  // yyyy
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

The string representation of a `Date` object is specified as `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy`. This is exactly what you're seeing.

If you want to display a `Date` object in a different format, use the `SimpleDateFormat` class. Its sole purpose is to add flexibility to the way a `Date` object is represented as a string.

---

*Also*...

One possible, albeit ridiculous workaround would be to create your own wrapper class,

```
public class MyDate{
    private final Date d;
    private final SimpleDateFormat sdf;

    public(Date d, SimpleDateFormat sdf){
        this.d = d;
        this.sdf = sdf;
    }

    // not recommended...should only be used for debugging purposes
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return sdf.format(d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use another `SimpleDateFormat` with the desired output format (`format()`)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `String` representation for a date using the same `SimpleDateFormat`. The [`format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29) method does this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date1 = sdf.parse("2012-07-27");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "format" property in [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). A `Date` instance is rather a simple object representing a moment in time (effectively, it's state is only defined by a unix timestamp it stores internally).

As others noted, use (for example) a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to print a `Date` instance as into a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = dateFormat.parse("2012-07-27");
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( "2012-07-27" )
         .toString()
```

> 2012-07-27

## Details

The modern way is with the java.time classes.

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

### Standard format

Your input string format happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings that represent date-time values. So no need to specify a formatting pattern at all.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2012-07-27" );
```

Do not conflate date-time objects with Strings representing their value. A date-time class/object can *parse* a string and *generate* a string, but the `String` is always a separate and distinct object.

```
String output = ld.toString();
```

> 2012-07-27

### Custom format

If your input is non-standard, define a `DateTimeFormatter` to match.

```
String input = "20-12-2005" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ld.toString(): 2012-07-27

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).