# Java DateFormat in Date Object

Tags: java, java.util.date

There is a simple problem of Date Format Conversion. In java when we print date object its in this format "Tue Nov 13 18:34:35 PKT 2012" But I want this date to be shown in this format "2012-11-13 18:34:35" with in Date object. No string is required. Only Date object is needed in above format. Can any one help me.
I am using

```
Date d = new Date();  
SimpleDateFormat sdf =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
Date formattedDate = sdf.parse(d.format(sdf));
```

Comment: A `java.util.Date` is just a date, which means that there's no *format*, just data. You format a date when you want to print/write it, and that using for example the `java.text.SimpleDateFormat#format()` method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300651/convert-string-to-date-in-java-in-format-2012-07-27/12300726#12300726

Answer (score 3):

> But I want this date to be shown in this format "2012-11-13 18:34:35" with in Date object. No string is required.

The format you talk about *is* a string. If no string is required, then your first requirement goes away completely. You want the date to be **shown**, which means a string *is* required.

A `Date` *has* no concept of a format. It's just a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch. There's no information within `Date` which controls the format.

Just use `SimpleDateFormat`, adjusting it to whatever format - and calendar, and time zone, and locale - you want. Don't waste time trying to change the `Date` itself, because you won't get anywhere. Treat `Date.toString()` as a diagnostic convenience and nothing more.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused. Formatting is only for display purpose, not for computation purpose. `Date()` object doesn't represent format, It is number of milliseconds of epoch time. Using `SimpleDateFormat` class `format()` method you can format the date and print as you wish.